# how to dynamically change dropdown menu in html from django template

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, html, django

I create a dictionary in django views.py like this:

```
tmp={"K1":['V1','V2'],"K2":['V3','V4']}
```

and in my html page,I create two dropdown menu.

menu D1 can select key from dictionary (K1/K2) in html:

```
<select name="D1"> 
   {% for key, value in tmp.items %} 
       <option value="{{key}}">{{key}}</option>
   {% endfor %}
</select>
```

now I want create menu D2 dynamically change with D1 select,for example, if I select K1 in D1,dropdown menu D2 will show V1 V2 and when I change to K2 in D1,menu D2 will show V3 V4,I suddenly don't know how to do it,can any one help me? very thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this use vanilla JavaScript or jQuery if you feel more comfortable with it. Add event listener on the first dropdown. You can prepare elements for example using jQuery:

```
var first_els = $("<option value="K1">V1</option><option value="K1">V2</option>");
var second_els = $("<option value="K2">V3</option><option value="K2">V4</option>");

function callback(){
    var value = this.value;
    if (value === "K1"){
      dropdown.append(second_els);
} 
    else{
     dropdown.append(first_els);
}

}
```

callback function is the function that is beeing called when something will be changed in dropdown 1. Of course you have to do more, like clear current elements in DOM or just fetch dropdown. But I hope this example gave you idea how to solve your problem